# Archived Post Is Ranking Instead of Actual Article

Tags: seo, google

I recently wrote an article that took the number 2 spot on Google for a specific search term. It was a pretty easily rankable term.

Two weeks later is was gone.

I've written articles that over time have not showed up on the first page of Google because others beat me out so my ranking starts to drop. That's fine, I understand that. It happens.

What's weird about this one is no other competitor articles have been written, and as I search on page 2 and 3 of Google, I come across my "Lifestyle Archive" page where that post has been archived. But the actual article itself doesn't show up. I don't get it! Does anyone know what happened and how I can get it back to the top of Google?

A few other things to note:

I have a video on the page, and that IS still ranking at the top in the video section.

Google console says the post is on Google. When I type the post name directly into the Google search bar, it comes up.

So why do I come across my Lifestyle Archive page instead of the actual post when I'm searching the keyword on Google?

If I delete my video from the page will I rank again? I would rather have my article rank than the video.

Help!

Thank you!